# UICollectionView insertSections error - NSInvalidArgumentException reason setObjectForKey object cannot be nil UICollectionViewItemKey

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uicollectionview

I'm getting an error using a UICollectionView as follows:

```
2013-11-29 17:29:07.832 Clients[34200:70b] 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil 
(key: <_UICollectionViewItemKey: 0x8da14f0> 
Type = DV ReuseID = (null) IndexPath = (null))'
```

And the code is as follows, where I essentially have two NSMutableArrays -- one containing all entries and the other used to reduce the entries to one section -- in this bit, I'm adding all the missing sections back in (hope that makes sense).

```
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    NSString *selectedMarketSector = [[[[_marketSectors objectAtIndex:0] clients] objectAtIndex:0] clientMarketSector];
    NSMutableIndexSet *insertSections = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];
    for (TBMarketSector* sector in _allMarketSectors) {
        if (![[[[sector clients] objectAtIndex:0] clientMarketSector ] isEqualToString:selectedMarketSector]) {
            [insertSections addIndex:[_allMarketSectors indexOfObject:sector]];
        }
    }
    _marketSectors = [self.allMarketSectors mutableCopy];
    [self.collectionView insertSections:insertSections];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [self setLayoutStyle:TBLayoutStacks animated:YES];
}];
```

The line that 'appears' to be causing the problem is the `[self.collectionView insertSections:insertSections];` but I'm wondering if there is something weird going on elsewhere...

Thanks for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: if(insertSections != nil)
{
[self.collectionView insertSections:insertSections];
}

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not, it seems this particular issue is actually relating to a `UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter` that I don't want.

I should have mentioned that this only started being a problem with iOS7 (not the first problem I've had with Collection Views after switching to iOS 7 either).

Anyway, my custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` implemented the `- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method and was returning some attributes for all supplementary views.

To fix this particular problem, I needed to add the following:

```
if ([kind isKindOfClass:[UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter class]])
    return nil;
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think I found similar issue in my custom `UICollectionViewLayout`. Have you fired the radar?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of crash can be if in method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView
```

You try to get in `dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind:` - view of type elementKindSectionHeader, when kind is elementKindSectionFooter.
Check is nib register for current kind.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Dmitry! Looks like a good answer, I would recommend using backticks to format the code to make it more readable. Just type a ` before and after the code.